# Split a string with garbled characters

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash

I downloaded a bunch of zip files with garbled characters. The file names looks like:

```
598»°   2Äêºó.zip

599»°   ²ÝÃ±¾ÅÈË.zip
```

I tried to write a script to rename file names in Linux system, so that the names of the above will become **598.zip** and **599.zip**.

I used `ls` and `grep` command to read all the zip file into a long string, called it **' total '** for example. Then I used `for loop`:

```
   for $name in $total; do

       mv $name $newname;

   done
```

Unfortunately, the script does not work here. Actually, the for loop will split the string $total by space.The names showed above has space characters. These extra space characters make the $name not match the actual name of the zip files. I don't know how to deal with it. Any help would appreciate!

Comment: Quote your variable to prevent splitting on whitespace.

Comment: May be this problem is related to the character encoding used in your shell profile. Try utf-8 to get a readable  representation

Answer (score 4):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.zip' | while read ie
do
  oe=$(awk NF=1 FPAT=[0-9]+ <<< "$ie").zip
  mv "$ie" $oe
done
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. However, the output looks like "598 2.zip", "599 .zip"

Comment: Why `1` reputation? :]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
Just add the following code before the script will do the trick:

```
   IFS='
  '
```

This will using newline as the internal field separator. Now the space is just "ordinary" character.

Answer (score 0):

FPAT is only supported in awk 4 and above version. You can use shell directly.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.zip' | while read file
do
  echo mv "$file" "${file/[^0-9]*/}"
done
```

if above script is fine, remove `echo`, and run again.